# Moving or copying file from one job template to another in azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two jobs in azure pipeline.one is `infrastructure.yml` and another is `keyvault.yml`. `keyvault.yml` is getting deployed first. Then `infrastructure.yml` is getting deployed.

I am downloading one certificate(pfx file) in `keyvault.yml` from storage account using following code:

```
az storage blob download \
        --blob-url "${blob_url}" \
        --file "${pfx_path}" \
        --sas-token "${cert_DownloadUrlToken_Custom}"
```

I want to use this downloaded certificate in `infrastructure.yml` job. I want to upload the certificate(pfx file) to another storage account in `infrastructure.yml` using following command

```
 az storage blob upload --account-name ${sa_name} \
        --account-key ${access_key} \
        --container-name "certificate" \
        --file "${pfx_path}" \
        --name "cert" \
        --overwrite true
```

. For now I am getting following

> error certificate not found

Is it possible to use cert file downloaded in one job in another job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use cert file downloaded in one job in another job?

Yes. To transfer files between different jobs or pipelines, you need to use `Publish Pipeline Artifact` task and `Download Pipeline Artifact` task.

Please refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml-task) for the details.

Comment: Hi @Aditya Purusharthi, how is it going? Please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Resolved after this.